# Reporting Service 2005: Dynamic Data Set

Tags: reporting-services

Let say I have query like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, Qty, Amount
FROM Source
```

I want to make this dynamic, so the user will be able to select `Column1` etc by using  checkbox. If the user select `Column2, Column3` the query will be :

```
SELECT Column2, Column3, SUM(QTY), SUM(AMOUNT) FROM Source 
GROUP BY Column2, Column3
```

In term of query, I can build this no problem in stored procedure but how to put this into `Reporting Service` in term of displaying it dynamically? Cause I know that the Table Report Item you have to set the value of field that is going to be displayed?

I am appreciated your help

Comment: Please mention the reporting tool being used, Crystal Report, Oracle Reports etc along with the version

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by not changing the query and hiding columns. You can prompt the user with the columns and have a Show/Hide or something similar.

[Here is an example of hiding columns I googled.](http://www.theruntime.com/blogs/thomasswilliams/archive/2008/09/29/hiding-and-showing-columns-based-on-a-parameter-in-reporting.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the Field element used to populate columns in a table can use an indexer like so: Field("Column1").Value. You can pass a string array containing these column names as a parameter to your report and use them as Field indexers.

Also most elements in the report can be controlled by expressions including visibility and grouping elements.